# Why is WebGL render speed so inconsistent?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, opengl-es-2.0, webgl

In my application I plot about 8 million vertices with a single call to WebGL's drawarrays using the LINE_STRIP flag.  I don't actually want one long line, I want about 200k short lines, so I cap all the short lines with extra vertices, and tell the vertex shader to "push" the line caps into negative z to create invisible bridges.  The rendering is quasi-static (the user can click various things that trigger a re-render) so it doesn't have to be super-fast, but I'd really hoped it would take less than 200ms on modernish computers.

On my laptop [*UPDATE:* which runs Win7 using a few Intel i7s as its CPU and an integrated HD Graphics 4000 for a GPU] I get around 100ms in Chrome, which is good.  Oddly though, Firefox gets around 1-2 seconds.  On my Samsung Chromebook 550 I get anything from 600ms to 2s, often it starts quick and then subsequent renders get slower but it can get faster too.

**Questions:**

- What might be causing the change in render speed on my Chromebook?
- Why is Firefox so much slower than Chrome on my laptop?
- Is it worth spending ages trying to make it run faster (i.e. can I expect much improvement)?  Any tips?

**Notes:**

- For the Chromebook repeated rendering tests, the only thing happening between renders is a uniform is changed to toggle between color palettes (implemented as textures). Chrome dev tools doesn't seem to think there are any major changes in the page's memory usage during the testing.
- I'm using gl.finish and console.time to see how long the rendering is taking.
- Except during debugging, I render to an orphaned canvas and then copy sections of the result to various small canvases on the page *UPDATE:* using drawImage (with the webgl canvas as the first argument).  This probably does take a bit of time, but the numbers reported above don't seem to change much with or without the copy operation and with or without the webgl canvas attached to the page body (and visible).
- *UPDATE:* There is a limit to how many vertices my laptop will render in one go, but the limit seems to fluctuate from moment to moment, if you go over the limit then it doesn't render anything.  The number is around the 8million mark, but sometimes it's happy to go over 11million. I've now set it to batch 2 million at a time.  Interestingly this seems to make my Chromebook go faster, but I can't be sure as it's so inconsistent.
- *UPDATE:* I've disabled DEPTH_TEST and BLEND as I don't need them. I'm not convinced it made any difference.
- *UPDATE:* I've tried rendering with POINTS instead of LINES.  On my Chromebook it seemed to take about 1s with 0 point size (i.e. rendering nothing), and then around 1.5-2s as I increased the point size through 1,2, and 5.
- *UPDATE:* Keeping everything on the z=0 plane doesn't seem to change the speed much, maybe it goes a little slower (which I'd expect as there are a lot more pixels to get through the fragment shader, though the fragment shader is just funneling a varying straight into gl_FragColor).

Comment: (1) I've seen bad handling of lines heading offscreen on low-end GPUs. I would try removing the line-cap vertices (i.e. let things be connected in nonsensical ways) and see what effect that has. (2) Don't use `gl.finish`; it may make things easier to measure but you will measure 'unrealistic' values compared to actual pipelined results.

Comment: Are you changing the vertices or indices or are they static? Every time you change indicies WebGL implementations have to scan to make sure they are all in range. They cache the result but updating the indices will kill the cache. Different drivers also react differently to updating vertices. If you are updating vertices you could try the various modes. STATIC_DRAW, DYNAMIC_DRAW, STREAM_DRAW and see if you get different results. Copying to a canvas is slow but is actively being optimized.

Comment: Kevin - regarding (1) that's the kind of technical answer I'd hoped fo but unfortunately it didn't seem to be the problem here (see update above); regarding (2) I'm only using that when I have the copying turned off, to check that it's not the copying that is slow.
Gman - I'm not changing anything other than uniforms, the vertices are left untouched in their buffer. I'm using STATIC_DRAW.  (I've been watching the IO2013 talks - it's great to see all the amazing stuff being done to get chrome going faster)

Answer (score 0):

Although the usual (good) advice is to render as much as possible in each draw call, some (at least one which I know of) GPUs have internal buffers used while processing vertex data. Exceeding the capacity of these buffers can make your performance fall off a cliff. Reduce the size of your vertex batches until you start to see a performance drop from having batches which are too small.